# Bootstrap V5 Navbar and Nested Dropdowns (Submenu, Multilevel, Megamenu) issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a **Navbar Nested Dropdown** *(Submenu, Multilevel and Mega Menu)* but I face some issues such as ash **sizing** `max-width` & `min-width` and **directions** `dropstart` & `dropend` based on page **viewport**.

**here is my code:**

**HTML**

```
<nav id="navbar-area" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light py-4">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-inline-flex align-items-center me-0 py-0" href="#">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="35" height="35" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bootstrap-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M6.375 7.125V4.658h1.78c.973 0 1.542.457 1.542 1.237 0 .802-.604 1.23-1.764 1.23H6.375zm0 3.762h1.898c1.184 0 1.81-.48 1.81-1.377 0-.885-.65-1.348-1.886-1.348H6.375v2.725z" />
                <path
                    d="M4.002 0a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v8a4 4 0 0 0 4 4h8a4 4 0 0 0 4-4V4a4 4 0 0 0-4-4h-8zm1.06 12V3.545h3.399c1.587 0 2.543.809 2.543 2.11 0 .884-.65 1.675-1.483 1.816v.1c1.143.117 1.904.931 1.904 2.033 0 1.488-1.084 2.396-2.888 2.396H5.062z"
                />
            </svg>
            <span class="text-primary fw-bold ms-3">Bootstrap.</span>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu dropstart">
                            <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Level 1.0 (Left) Item</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu">
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-multilevel dropstart">
                                    <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Level 2.2 (Left) Item</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-multilevel">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Level 3.3 (Left) Item</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu dropend">
                            <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Level 1.0 (Right) Item</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu">
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-multilevel dropend">
                                    <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Level 2.2 (Right) Item</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-multilevel">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Level 3.3 (Right) Item</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-megamenu dropend">
                            <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Mega Menu Item</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-megamenu">
                                <div class="row row-cols-4 g-0">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li><h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header</h6></li>
                                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li><h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header</h6></li>
                                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li><h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header</h6></li>
                                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li><h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header</h6></li>
                                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">
                    <a href="#" role="button" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Mega Menu</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-megamenu">
                        <div class="row row-cols-4 g-0">
                            <div class="col">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li><h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header</h6></li>
                                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li><h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header</h6></li>
                                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li><h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header</h6></li>
                                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li><h6 class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header</h6></li>
                                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 15rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 20px 30px rgba(83, 88, 93, 0.05), 0px 0px 30px rgba(83, 88, 93, 0.1);
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.625rem;
    left: 2.188rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #4361ee;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #202020;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu.dropstart .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu.dropstart .dropdown-menu:before {
    content: none;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu.dropstart.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu.dropdown-submenu,
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu.dropstart.dropdown-multilevel .dropdown-menu.dropdown-submenu {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu.dropstart.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu.dropdown-submenu {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu.dropend .dropdown-item.dropdown-toggle::before,
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-megamenu.dropend .dropdown-item.dropdown-toggle::before {
    border: none;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu.dropend .dropdown-menu,
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-megamenu.dropend .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu.dropend .dropdown-menu:before,
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-megamenu.dropend .dropdown-menu:before {
    content: none;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu.dropend.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu.dropdown-submenu,
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu.dropend.dropdown-multilevel .dropdown-menu.dropdown-submenu {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown .dropdown-menu .dropdown-submenu.dropend.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu.dropdown-submenu {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown.has-megamenu {
    position: static;
}
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown.has-megamenu .dropdown-menu.dropdown-megamenu {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1299px) and (max-width: 1500px) {
    #navbar-area .container {
        max-width: 1330px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    #navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown.has-megamenu .dropdown-menu.dropdown-megamenu {
        max-width: 960px;
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(".dropdown-menu [data-bs-toggle='dropdown']").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    $(this).parents(".dropdown-menu").first().find(".show").removeClass("show");
    $(this).parents(".dropdown-menu").first().find("[aria-expanded='true']").attr("aria-expanded", false);

    $(this).attr("aria-expanded", true);
    $(this).siblings(".dropdown-menu").toggleClass("show");

    $(this)
        .parents(".nav-item.dropdown")
        .on("hidden.bs.dropdown", function (e) {
            $(".dropdown-submenu .show").removeClass("show");
            $(".dropdown-submenu [aria-expanded='true']").attr("aria-expanded", false);
        });
});
```

**live example:**

https://codepen.io/themes4all/full/abWvBwE

Answer (score 0):

I can see the issue is in Mega Menu, it goes to far left in desktop.
My simple solution will for this
update this

for

(min-width: 992px)

```
#navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown.has-megamenu .dropdown-menu.dropdown-megamenu {
    max-width: 960px;
}
```

to this

```
  #navbar-area .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown.has-megamenu .dropdown-menu.dropdown-megamenu {
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 90vh;
    left: auto;
    right: 10vh;
}
```

you can update right positioning for larger screen size.